# Highlight missing double-space between sentences?

Tags: whitespace, highlighting, sentences

For a while, I've been using `sentence-end-double-space: nil`. Now I want to get back into the habit of using two spaces to separate sentences. It is the convention for GNU documentation, and it actually makes sense: That way periods after abbreviations can semantically be differentiated from periods at the end of a sentence. Still, when typing, I forget to write the double space.

*Is there a mode that helps me highlight my omissions?*

Of course, it would also highlight a single space after an abbreviation, but that's fine.

Note that if `sentence-end-double-space: nil` has been set for the current buffer, then single spaces should *not* be highlighted.

Comment: `flycheck-mode` does that in elisp doc-strings. Otherwise you can use `highlight-regexp` with regular expression `\. [^[:space:]]`. You can even put `(highlight-regexp "\\. [^[:space:]]")` into the hook of the major mode you use for your documents.

Comment: An enhancement to add this to `whitespace-style` might be useful, but it would need to be limited to relevant modes, such as `text-mode`. Maybe a separate `whitespace-mode` option would be appropriate, to allow `whitespace-style` to continue to specify more general behavior. If you want to request such an enhancement, use `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Tobias: Please consider posting your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Drew I will do that eventually if nobody else comes up with a better answer. But I will wait for two or three days. Giving an answer that does not exactly fit what the OP wants is sometimes worse than giving no answer since the question does no longer draw as much attention as one without any answers. I put the question on my favorites and a remainder into my calendar (which is BTW an org-mode thing;-).

Comment: @Tobias: Yes, sounds good. Thx.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks for the suggestion. As there is no answer yet, I decided to add an additional requirement to make this really useful: If `sentence-end-double-space: nil`, then there should be no highlighting.

Comment: The conventional way is to activate or deactivate some minor mode as I have proposed it in my answer.

Comment: @Drew I have considered adding the functionality to `whitespace.el`. Pitingly the implementation of `whitespace.el` does not allow simple add-ons for new features. Instead of an alist of features and corresponding functions they treat the features in one big `cond` form:-(. That is the reason why I rolled a separate library for highlighting double-space in [my answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48479/2370). Best regards, Tobias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [my comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48397/highlight-missing-double-space-between-sentences#comment74816_48397) I suggested to use `highlight-regexp`. But meanwhile I discovered that that method does not keep the highlighting correctly updated (it actually should).

So I wrote up a minor mode `hlds-mode` that does the job.
I assume that with this minor mode the variable `sentence-end-double-space` becomes obsolete.

You just only hook the minor mode into those major modes where you want the highlighting and you can even switch on or off the minor mode with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `hlds-mode` if you decide late that you do like or not like the highlighting for that specific buffer.

```el
(defface hlds
  '((((class color) (background dark))
     :background "grey" :foreground "darkgray")
    (((class color) (background light))
     :background "yellow"  :foreground "lightgray")
    (t :inverse-video t))
  "Face used to mark missing sentence separating double spaces."
  :group 'hlds)

(defvar hlds-re "\\.\\( \\)[^[:space:]]"
  "Regular expression for marking missing double spaces as sentence separators.")

(defun hlds-clear (start end)
  "Clear hlds fontification in region from START to END."
  (with-silent-modifications 
    (cl-loop for int being the intervals property 'face from start to end
         if (eq (get-text-property (car int) 'face) 'hlds)
         do (remove-text-properties (car int) (cdr int) '(face hdls)))))

(defun hlds-jitlock-handler (start end)
  "Mark double spaces in region from START to END."
  (save-excursion
   (with-silent-modifications
     (hlds-clear start end)
     (goto-char (max (- start 2) 1))
     (when (< end (point-max))
       (cl-incf end))
     (while (re-search-forward hlds-re end t)
       (put-text-property (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) 'face 'hlds)))))

(defvar-local hlds-font-lock-keywords nil
  "Additional `font-lock-keywors' entries for hdls-mode.")

(define-minor-mode hlds-mode
  "Highlight missing double-spaces that should separate sentences."
  nil
  " ds"
  nil
  (if hlds-mode
      (if font-lock-mode
      (progn
        (font-lock-add-keywords
         nil
         (setq hlds-font-lock-keywords `((,hlds-re 1 'hlds))))
        (save-restriction
          (widen)
          (font-lock-flush)
          (font-lock-ensure)))
    (unless jit-lock-mode (jit-lock-mode t))
    (jit-lock-register #'hlds-jitlock-handler)
    (jit-lock-fontify-now (point-min) (point-max)))
    (when font-lock-mode
      (font-lock-remove-keywords nil hlds-font-lock-keywords)
      (save-restriction
    (widen)
    (font-lock-flush (point-min) (point-max))))
    (when jit-lock-mode
      (save-restriction
    (widen)
    (hlds-clear (point-min) (point-max)))
      (jit-lock-unregister #'hlds-jitlock-handler))))
```

For obtaining the effect that the file-local variable `sentence-end-double-space` controls the activation of `hlds-mode` you can define a corresponding globalized mode. The TURN-ON function `hlds-turn-on` turns on `hlds-mode` if the automagically selected major mode for the file buffer is registered in `sentence-end-double-space`. If you annihilate the value of `sentence-end-double-space` file-locally `hlds-mode` is not switched on in the corresponding file buffer.

```el
(defcustom hlds-major-mode-list '(text-mode fundamental-mode)
  "Major modes with `hlds-mode' turned on by default."
  :type '(repeat :tag "Major modes" symbol)
  :group 'hlds)

(defun hlds-turn-on ()
  "Turn on `hlds-mode' in the current buffer."
  (when (and (apply #'derived-mode-p hlds-major-mode-list)
             sentence-end-double-space)
    (hlds-mode)))

(define-globalized-minor-mode global-hlds-mode hlds-mode hlds-turn-on)

(global-hlds-mode) ;; Just turn the global mode on.
```

Tested with `emacs -Q` with code in `*scratch*` buffer. One file with file-local setting `sentence-end-double-space: nil` and one without.

Emacs-Version: GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2018-05-29

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that! Respect for `sentence-end-double-space: nil` is still however a requirement. I have thousands of `text-mode` files, some with, some without `sentence-end-double-space: nil`.

Comment: @feklee Do you use `sentence-end-double-space` as a file-local variable? Okay then this is maybe a control flag for a globalized minor mode.

Comment: Yes, for example: `Local Variables:
mode: text
fill-column: 80
sentence-end-double-space: nil
coding: utf-8
End:
Local IspellDict: american`

Comment: @feklee I added how you can define a globalized minor mode that is controlled by `sentence-end-double-space: nil`.

Comment: @feklee Okay I just got the meaning of `sentence-end-double-space`. I will correct that.

Comment: @feklee There was a macro `save-point` from my own libraries in the code. I've replaced that with `save-excursion`. Furthermore, I've corrected the usage of `sentence-end-double-space`. The code should work now with `emacs -Q`. Could you please test it?

Comment: According to first tests, this works great! I adapted the regular expression to: `"[.!?]\\( \\)[^[:space:]]"`.  This matches the spacing that `fill-paragraph` uses, i.e. two spaces after period, exclamation mark, or question mark.  It’s also possible to tell `fill-paragraph` to add two spaces after colons by setting `colon-double-space` to non-nil.  There may be additional rules.